# Jenkins Performance Plugin for Jmeter

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, performance-testing

I am currently using Performance plugin v 1.13 on Jenkins 1.583 for integrating and reporting Jmeter results. The plugin overall works fine except for the error rate which is constantly reported as 100% although the actual JTL log contains no error records. I know this is an existing bug with this plugin but I am hoping if someone has found a workaround for this issue. I downgraded to v 1.11 but without luck. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes indeed, this is defect JENKINS-28426 and only obvious workaround seem to be switch to CSV.

However, I'd suggest you to take a look at the [entire bug list](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-28426?jql=project%20%3D%20JENKINS%20AND%20status%20in%20%28Open%2C%20%22In%20Progress%22%2C%20Reopened%29%20AND%20component%20%3D%20%27performance-plugin%27) of this plugin. This particular issue was logged in May and didn't attract too much attention so far. Similar case with other defects.

I need a confidence in tools which give me confidence in software I'm working on. I have no confidence in Jenkins Performance Plugin. Think what you use this plugin for and look for the alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the problem by switching report format to xml in jmeter properties file, like so:
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml